# why is java servlet attaching 2 files to email but both are the same?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-mail

i am sending out emails using `javax.mail`

here is my method of attaching

```
private static void addAttachment(MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart, Multipart multipart, String fileName, File fileToAttach) throws MessagingException{
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fileToAttach);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

}
```

i use mysql to set file names and to query files from url to download like this

```
    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT url, id, name FROM db WHERE surl != '' LIMIT 2 ");

    while(rs.next()){
        String fileName = rs.getString("name") + rs.getString("id") + ".png";
        out.println(rs.getString("url"));
        url = new URL(rs.getString("url"));
        f = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\asAttach"+ rs.getString("id") +".png");

        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, f);

        addAttachment(messageBodyPart, multipart, fileName, f);             
    }
```

they keep attaching two files but both are the same.

Comment: Have you checked the data returned by that query on your db ? How many records are returned ?  And why the "LIMIT 2" if you only need one ?

Comment: i am trying to attach multiple images to one email. The images are downloaded using the `url` from the db. then they are attached. The reason I am using `LIMIT 2` is because I want to attach 2 images to the email.

Answer (score 0):

here is how I got it to work.

```
private static void addAttachment(Multipart multipart, String fileName, String filePath) throws MessagingException{
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filePath);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

}
```

i didnt give the method the MimeBodyPart.

here is how I used it.

```
            URL url = new URL(rs.getString("url"));
            File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\asAttach"+ rs.getString("id") +".png");

            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, f);

            addAttachment(multipart, fileName, f.toString());
```

you can use this in a loop and attach as many files as possible.